# Nuget Package downloaded to wrong directory

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

When downloading a Nuget Package using the following code, said package is added, as expected, to my MachineWideConfigDirectory.

However, the folder it is added to is something like:

`.nuget/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.6.0.0`

instead of:

`.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/6.0.0`.

Any idea on how to get it working properly?

*Code to programatically download the package:*

```cs
var settings = Settings.LoadDefaultSettings(string.Empty, null, new MachineWideSettings());
var packageSourceProvider = new PackageSourceProvider(settings);
var sourceRepositoryProvider = new SourceRepositoryProvider(packageSourceProvider, Providers);
var framework = NuGetFramework.Parse(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()!.GetCustomAttribute<TargetFrameworkAttribute>()!.FrameworkName!);

var package = await this.GetPackageAsync(this.PackageId, this.PackageVersion, this.IncludePreRelease, false, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException($"Failed to find the specified package with id '{this.PackageId}' and version '{this.PackageVersion}'");
var project = new PluginNugetProject(this.PackagesDirectory.FullName, this.PluginDirectory.FullName, package.Identity, framework);
var packageManager = new NuGetPackageManager(sourceRepositoryProvider, settings, this.PackagesDirectory.FullName) { PackagesFolderNuGetProject = project };
var clientPolicyContext = ClientPolicyContext.GetClientPolicy(settings, this.NugetLogger);
var projectContext = new PluginNugetProjectContext(this.LoggerFactory) { PackageExtractionContext = new PackageExtractionContext(PackageSaveMode.Defaultv3, PackageExtractionBehavior.XmlDocFileSaveMode, clientPolicyContext, this.NugetLogger) };
var resolutionContext = new ResolutionContext(DependencyBehavior.Lowest, true, false, VersionConstraints.None);
var downloadContext = new PackageDownloadContext(resolutionContext.SourceCacheContext, this.PackagesDirectory.FullName, resolutionContext.SourceCacheContext.DirectDownload);

await packageManager.InstallPackageAsync(project, package.Identity, resolutionContext, projectContext, downloadContext, package.SourceRepository, new List<SourceRepository>(), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
await project.PostProcessAsync(projectContext, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
await project.PreProcessAsync(projectContext, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
await packageManager.RestorePackageAsync(package.Identity, projectContext, downloadContext, new[] { package.SourceRepository }, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

*MachineWideSettings:*

```cs
class MachineWideSettings
    : IMachineWideSettings
{

    public ISettings Settings => NuGet.Configuration.Settings.LoadMachineWideSettings(NuGetEnvironment.GetFolderPath(NuGetFolderPath.MachineWideConfigDirectory));

}
```

Edit:

Here's my `nuget.config`, as requested by @jakub-podhaisky:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you share nuget.config please ? 
I had a similar problem in the past and it was solved by changing a repositoryPath inside nuget.config

Comment: You're probably using the APIs created for packages.config projects, whereas the directory layout you want is the global packages directory layout. You'll need to change your PluginNuGetProject to extend BuildIntegratedNuGetProject, then use the appropriate NuGetPackageManager API for build integrated projects, and make sure the `ISettings` you pass in sets `globalPackagesFolder` to the location you want it saved.

Comment: If your plugin packages don't have dependencies, it will be much easier to use `SourceRepository` from NuGet.Protocol and `PackageExtractor` from NuGet.Packaging directly.  NuGet.PackageManagement has no public API reviews and is designed around the VS package manager UI, so is very difficult to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct paths to consider here: the "project related" package directory and the global NuGet cache directory. It's essential to differentiate between them for a clearer understanding of the issue.

It appears that your confusion stems from configuring your "project" directory to function similarly to the "global cache" directory. My assumption is based on the structure outlined in [Dave Glick’s articles](https://www.daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-3), and `PluginNugetProject` extends `FolderNuGetProject`.

It seems you’re passing `.nuget/packages/` as your project root directory when creating your instance of `PluginNugetProject`.

Additionally, the `FolderNuGetProject` can be constructed by passing a [`PackagePathResolver`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f30f921581f84774f8b916ff3384b5ec0ab2b1c1/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.PackageManagement/Projects/FolderNuGetProject.cs#L54), which in turn, accepts a `useSideBySidePath` argument. When set to true (which is the default behavior), the PackagePathResolver concatenates your project root folder with the package identifier and version you're installing.

Consequently, the final installation directory for a specific package will be `$"{projectRoot}/{packageIdentity.Id}.{packageIdentity.Version}"`, resulting in `.nuget/packages/` + `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` + `.` + `6.0.0`.

However, you might wonder why the global cache directory isn't created. There should ideally be a directory structure like `.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/6.0.0`.

Understanding this behavior requires further investigation into the NuGet client sources. When building your `ResolutionContext`, you don't pass any [`SourceCacheContext`](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f30f921581f84774f8b916ff3384b5ec0ab2b1c1/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.PackageManagement/Context/ResolutionContext.cs#L18). Consequently, the `NullSourceCacheContext` is utilized, with its [`DirectDownload` property set to true by default](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/f30f921581f84774f8b916ff3384b5ec0ab2b1c1/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Protocol/NullSourceCacheContext.cs#L18).

As the name suggests, direct download bypasses the global NuGet directory and downloads the package directly to its destination.

To enable the global caching mechanism and cache your package in `.nuget/packages/microsoft.extensions.logging/6.0.0`, set `resolutionContext.SourceCacheContext.DirectDownload = false;`.

In conclusion, depending on your use case, you have two options:

- Implement and provide your own PackagePathResolver.
- Set DirectDownload to false.

Each option has its implications and trade-offs, so consider your requirements carefully.